# Failure to download file with sftp

Tags: usb, ssh

I Raspberry Pi 2 as a Torrent Box. I recently attach to it an external usb HDD formatted in NTFS. I can download successfully any file in the hardisk but when I try to connect to my Raspberry with Filezilla and trying to download file stored in the external disk I got this error message:

```
error while reading: received failure with description 'Failure'
Transfer Failed
```

I also run the command `df -h` to see how much free space I have and this is the output:

```
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/root       5,9G  3,9G    1,8G  69% /
devtmpfs        458M     0    458M   0% /dev
tmpfs           462M     0    462M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           462M  6,5M    456M   2% /run
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           462M     0    462M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   65M   21M     45M  33% /boot  
/dev/sda1       233G  875M    233G   1% /media/pi/external-hardisk
tmpfs            93M     0     93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I don't have any problem with the space.
The permissions of the folder are given recursively and are:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 dic 16 17:30 external-hardisk
```

So, what is the problem?